# Resampling a pandas Series

Tags: pandas

I have a simple time series

```
2014-11-17 05:00:00+00:00  1.30367
2014-11-17 05:01:00+00:00  1.30352
2014-11-17 05:02:00+00:00  1.30382
2014-11-17 05:03:00+00:00  1.30373
2014-11-17 05:04:00+00:00  1.30425
2014-11-17 05:05:00+00:00  1.30399
2014-11-17 05:06:00+00:00  1.30378
```

I want to resample using "2min", e.g. ideally I want to get

```
2014-11-17 05:01:00+00:00  1.30352
2014-11-17 05:03:00+00:00  1.30373
2014-11-17 05:05:00+00:00  1.30399
2014-11-17 05:07:00+00:00  1.30378
```

The built-in resampling gives me

```
2014-11-17 05:00:00+00:00    1.30367
2014-11-17 05:02:00+00:00    1.30382
2014-11-17 05:04:00+00:00    1.30425
2014-11-17 05:06:00+00:00    1.30378
```

I am using series.resample(rule="2min", label="right", closed="right").last()
I am in particular puzzled by the first point.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use `label='right'`, instead use `loffset`:

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas


data = StringIO("""\
2014-11-17 05:00:00+00:00,1.30367
2014-11-17 05:01:00+00:00,1.30352
2014-11-17 05:02:00+00:00,1.30382
2014-11-17 05:03:00+00:00,1.30373
2014-11-17 05:04:00+00:00,1.30425
2014-11-17 05:05:00+00:00,1.30399
2014-11-17 05:06:00+00:00,1.30378
""")

window = pandas.offsets.Minute(2)

df = (
    pandas.read_csv(data, parse_dates=[0], header=None, names=['dt', 'value'])
        .set_index(['dt'])
        .resample(window, loffset=window/2)
        .last()
)
```

That gives me:

```
                             value
dt                                
2014-11-17 05:01:00+00:00  1.30352
2014-11-17 05:03:00+00:00  1.30373
2014-11-17 05:05:00+00:00  1.30399
2014-11-17 05:07:00+00:00  1.30378
```

Comment: Great, many thanks. I don't think you want to use window/2. It's correct for a window of two minutes. Better use window - 1

Comment: @tschm Well that depends on what you're trying to do. Your question seems like you wanted the labels to be in the middle of the window

Comment: I see. My example wasn't the best. I try to resample close prices of 1min bar data where the time corresponds to the right edge of the bar.